# how to use preg_replace function in php in my quiz system correctly

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a quiz system. I have this table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE fill_gap_exercise (
  quiz_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  text VARCHAR,
  wordslist VARCHAR,
  date DATETIME
)
```

Here is an example data row from the table:

```
INSERT INTO fill_gap_exercise
  (quiz_id, text, wordslist, date)
VALUES
  (4, 'hello {0} up {1}', 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"whats";i:1;s:5:"men??";}', '2012-10-29 13:24:25')
```

I'm trying to replace `{}` characters within the `text` field, but I am having a problem when the sentence has multiple occurrences of the `{}` sequence.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  include('../connect_db.php');

  $myData = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM fill_gap_exercise');

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {    

    $array = unserialize($row['wordslist']);
    $text  = implode('\r\n', $array);

    echo "\n<br />";

    $pattern = '/\{(.*)\}/';
    $replace = '<input type="text" name="j_1" id="' . $row["quiz_id"] . '" />';
    $subject = $row['text'];
    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);

    print $string;    
  }
```

Comment: And your question is? What does not work? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Please don't store data serialised to string in a relational database like this. Use a `quiz_words` table instead to maintain the relationships, it will make many things much easier.

Comment: im new in php and I did not think this.. the answer of Vadim Ashikhman solved my problem! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Lazy quantificator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification)

Replace `'/\{(.*)\}/'` with `'/\{(.*?)\}/'`

Comment: ok is what i need! thanks a lot! and one more question. i need help about validation. when user write the appropriate word how can i check if this answer is right?

Comment: I assume there can be several words. Get the right words and place them in an array, then create another array for submitted words and use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: in my case there is the field wordslist that contains the right words .. i get confused on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need the position counter anyway, so why not simply fetch it from the string? Takes automagically away the [greedy/non-greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) issue.

E.g.

```
<?php
$row = array("quiz_id"=>47);
$string = 'hello {0}, up {1}?';

$string = preg_replace('/{(\d+)}/', '<input type="text" name="q['.$row["quiz_id"].'][\\1]" />', $string);

echo $string;
```

prints

```
hello <input type="text" name="q[47][0]" />, up <input type="text" name="q[47][1]" />?
```

Comment: this confuse me because I dont have much experience .. i have a lot of rows.. how can I customize this in mine?? also, i have problem on how to do the validation after, any ideas?? unfortunately I am new and i have problem with this issue..